# Is there a Codensity MonadPlus that asymptotically optimizes a sequence of MonadPlus operations?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory, free-monad, monadplus

Recently there was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32191851/1333025) about the relation between `DList` <-> `[]` versus `Codensity` <-> `Free`.

This made me think whether there is such a thing for `MonadPlus`. The `Codensity` monad improves the asymptotic performance only for the monadic operations, not for `mplus`.

Moreover, while there used to be `Control.MonadPlus.Free`, it has been [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32185389/1333025) in favor of `FreeT f []`. And since there is no explicit free `MonadPlus`, I'm not sure how one would express a corresponding [`improve`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-4.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html#improve) variant. Perhaps something like

```
improvePlus :: Functor f => (forall m. (MonadFree f m, MonadPlus m) => m a) -> FreeT f [] a
```

?

---

**Update:** I attempted to create such a monad using the backtracking [`LogicT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Logic.html#t:LogicT) monad, which seems to be defined in a way similar to `Codensity`:

> ```
> newtype LogicT r m a = LogicT { unLogicT :: forall r. (a -> m r -> m r) -> m r -> m r }
> ```

and is suited for backtracking computations, that is, `MonadPlus`.

Then I defined `lowerLogic`, similar to [`lowerCodensity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-3.7/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html#v:lowerCodensity) as followd:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, MultiParamTypeClasses,
             UndecidableInstances, DeriveFunctor #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free
import Control.Monad.Logic

lowerLogic :: (MonadPlus m) => LogicT m a -> m a
lowerLogic k = runLogicT k (\x k -> mplus (return x) k) mzero
```

Then, after supplementing the corresponding `MonadFree` instance

```
instance (Functor f, MonadFree f m) => MonadFree f (LogicT m) where
    wrap t = LogicT (\h z -> wrap (fmap (\p -> runLogicT p h z) t))
```

one can define

```
improvePlus :: (Functor f, MonadPlus mr)
            => (forall m. (MonadFree f m, MonadPlus m) => m a)
            -> FreeT f mr a
improvePlus k = lowerLogic k
```

However, something isn't right with it, as it seems from my initial experiments that for some examples `k` is distinct from `improvePlus k`. I'm not sure, if this is a fundamental limitation of `LogicT` and a different, more complex monad is needed, or just if I defined `lowerLogic` (or something else) wrongly.

Comment: This [paper](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~tom.schrijvers/Research/papers/ppdp2015.pdf) is very relevant to your question. "This paper provides a new algebraic understanding of the operations
of the MonadPlus type class, one that enables us to derive
both the free structure and an optimised Cayley-like representation."

Comment: Can you give an example of when `k` is different from `improvePlus k` for your implementation of the `LogicT` monad transformer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following is all based on my (mis)understanding of this very
interesting paper posted by Matthew Pickering in his
comment: [*From monoids to near-semirings: the essence of MonadPlus and
Alternative* (E. Rivas, M. Jaskelioff, T. Schrijvers)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/34635492.pdf). All results are theirs; all mistakes are mine.

### From free monoids to `DList`

To build up the intuition, first consider the free monoid `[]` over
the category of Haskell types `Hask`. One problem with `[]` is that if
you have

```
(xs `mappend` ys) `mappend` zs = (xs ++ ys) ++ zs
```

then evaluating that requires traversing and re-traversing `xs` for
each left-nested application of `mappend`.

The solution is to use CPS in the form of [difference
lists](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list):

```
newtype DList a = DL { unDL :: [a] -> [a] }
```

The paper considers the generic form of this (called the Cayley
representation) where we're not tied to the free monoid:

```
newtype Cayley m = Cayley{ unCayley :: Endo m }
```

with conversions

```
toCayley :: (Monoid m) => m -> Cayley m
toCayley m = Cayley $ Endo $ \m' -> m `mappend` m'

fromCayley :: (Monoid m) => Cayley m -> m
fromCayley (Cayley k) = appEndo k mempty
```

### Two directions of generalization

We can generalize the above construction in two ways: first, by
considering monoids not over `Hask`, but over endofunctors of `Hask`;
[i.e.](https://tailcalled.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/translation-of-monads-are-just-monoids-in-the-category-of-endofunctors/)
monads; and second, by enriching the algebraic structure into
near-semirings.

### `Free` monads to `Codensity`

For any Haskell (endo)functor `f`, we can construct the [free
monad](http://comonad.com/reader/2008/monads-for-free/) `Free f`, and
it will have the analogous performance problem with left-nested binds,
with the analogous solution of using the Cayley representation
[`Codensity`](http://comonad.com/reader/2011/free-monads-for-less/).

### Near-semirings instead of just monoids

This is where the paper stops reviewing concepts that are well-known
by the working Haskell programmer, and starts homing in on its goal. A
near-semiring is like a ring, except simpler, since both addition and
multiplication are just required to be monoids. The connection between
the two operations is what you expect:

```
zero |*| a = zero
(a |+| b) |*| c = (a |*| c) |+| (b |*| c)
```

where `(zero, |+|)` and `(one, |*|)` are the two monoids over some
shared base:

```
class NearSemiring a where
    zero :: a
    (|+|) :: a -> a -> a
    one :: a
    (|*|) :: a -> a -> a
```

The free near-semiring (over `Hask`) turns out to be the following
`Forest` type:

```
newtype Forest a = Forest [Tree a]
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Forest a)

instance NearSemiring (Forest a) where
    zero = Forest []
    one = Forest [Leaf]
    (Forest xs) |+| (Forest ys) = Forest (xs ++ ys)
    (Forest xs) |*| (Forest ys) = Forest (concatMap g xs)
      where
        g Leaf = ys
        g (Node a n) = [Node a (n |*| (Forest ys))]
```

(good thing we don't have commutativity or inverses,
[those make free representations far from
trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388004/whats-a-good-way-to-represent-free-groups)...)

Then, the paper applies the Cayley representation twice, to the two
monoidal structures.

> However, if we do this naively, we do
>   not get a good representation: we want to represent a near-semiring,
>   and therefore the whole near-semiring structure must be taken into
>   account and not just one chosen monoid structure. [...] [W]e obtain
>   the semiring of endomorphisms over endomorphisms `DC(N)`:

```
newtype DC n = DC{ unDC :: Endo (Endo n) }

instance (Monoid n) => NearSemiring (DC n) where
    f |*| g = DC $ unDC f `mappend` unDC g
    one = DC mempty
    f |+| g = DC $ Endo $ \h -> appEndo (unDC f) h `mappend` h
    zero = DC $ Endo $ const mempty
```

(I've changed the implementation here slightly from the paper to
emphasize that we are using the `Endo` structure twice). When we'll
generalize this, the two layers will not be the same. The paper then
goes on to say:

> Note that `rep` is not a near-semiring homomorphism from `N` into `DC(N)`
>   as it does not preserve the unit [...] Nevertheless, [...] the
>   semantics of a computation over a near-semiring will be preserved if
>   we lift values to the representation, do the near-semiring computation
>   there, and then go back to the original near-semiring.

### `MonadPlus` is almost a near-semiring

The paper then goes on to reformulate the `MonadPlus` typeclass so
that it corresponds to the near-semiring rules: `(mzero, mplus)` is monoidal:

```
m `mplus` mzero = m
mzero `mplus` m = m
m1 `mplus` (m2 `mplus` m3) = (m1 `mplus` m2) `mplus` m3
```

and it interacts with the monad-monoid as expected:

```
join mzero = mzero
join (m1 `mplus` m2) = join m1 `mplus` join m2
```

Or, using binds:

```
mzero >>= _ = mzero
(m1 `mplus` m2) >>= k = (m1 >>= k) `mplus` (m2 >>= k)
```

However, these are **not** the rules of the [existing `MonadPlus`
typeclass from
`base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus),
which are listed as:

```
mzero >>= _  =  mzero
_ >> mzero   =  mzero
```

The paper calls `MonadPlus` instances that satisfy the
near-semiring-like laws "nondeterminism monads", and 
cites `Maybe` as an example that is a `MonadPlus` but not a
nondeterminism monad, since setting `m1 = Just Nothing` and `m2 = Just
(Just False)` is a counter-example to `` join (m1 `mplus` m2) = join m1
`mplus` join m2 ``.

### Free and Cayley representation of nondeterminism monads

Putting everything together, on one hand we have the `Forest`-like
free nondeterminism monad:

```
newtype FreeP f x = FreeP { unFreeP :: [FFreeP f x] }
data FFreeP f x = PureP x | ConP (f (FreeP f x))

instance (Functor f) => Functor (FreeP f) where
    fmap f x = x >>= return . f

instance (Functor f) => Monad (FreeP f) where
    return x = FreeP $ return $ PureP x
    (FreeP xs) >>= f = FreeP (xs >>= g)
      where
        g (PureP x) = unFreeP (f x)
        g (ConP x) = return $ ConP (fmap (>>= f) x)

instance (Functor f) => MonadPlus (FreeP f) where
    mzero = FreeP mzero
    FreeP xs `mplus` FreeP ys = FreeP (xs `mplus` ys)
```

and on the other, the double-Cayley representation of the two monoidal
layers:

```
newtype (:^=>) f g x = Ran{ unRan :: forall y. (x -> f y) -> g y }
newtype (:*=>) f g x = Exp{ unExp :: forall y. (x -> y) -> (f y -> g y) }

instance Functor (g :^=> h) where
    fmap f m = Ran $ \k -> unRan m (k . f)

instance Functor (f :*=> g) where
    fmap f m = Exp $ \k -> unExp m (k . f)

newtype DCM f x = DCM {unDCM :: ((f :*=> f) :^=> (f :*=> f)) x}

instance Monad (DCM f) where
    return x = DCM $ Ran ($x)
    DCM (Ran m) >>= f = DCM $ Ran $ \g -> m $ \a -> unRan (unDCM (f a)) g

instance MonadPlus (DCM f) where
    mzero = DCM $ Ran $ \k -> Exp (const id)
    mplus m n = DCM $ Ran $ \sk -> Exp $ \f fk -> unExp (a sk) f (unExp (b sk) f fk)
      where
        DCM (Ran a) = m
        DCM (Ran b) = n

caylize :: (Monad m) => m a -> DCM m a
caylize x = DCM $ Ran $ \g -> Exp $ \h m -> x >>= \a -> unExp (g a) h m

-- I wish I called it DMC earlier...
runDCM :: (MonadPlus m) => DCM m a -> m a
runDCM m = unExp (f $ \x -> Exp $ \h m -> return (h x) `mplus` m) id mzero
  where
    DCM (Ran f) = m
```

The paper gives the following example of a computation running in a
nondeterminism monad that will behave poorly for `FreeP`:

```
anyOf :: (MonadPlus m) => [a] -> m a
anyOf [] = mzero
anyOf (x:xs) = anyOf xs `mplus` return x
```

Indeed, while

```
length $ unFreeP (anyOf [1..100000] :: FreeP Identity Int)
```

takes ages, the Cayley-transformed version

```
length $ unFreeP (runDCM $ anyOf [1..100000] :: FreeP Identity Int)
```

returns instantly.

Comment: It seems like the `LogicT` monad transformer is enough for efficient `MonadPlus` operations. No need for the complexity of `DCM`. In particular, we can redefine the `:*=>` newtype as `newtype (:*=>) f g x = Exp { unExp :: f x -> g x }`, update the rest of the code accordingly and everything would still work as expected. This is because the `(x -> y)` morphism in the current definition of `Exp` is unnecessary. The only value we provide for this type is `id` in the definition of `runDCM`.